# How many different ways are there to write $2016$ as the difference of two squares?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> How many different ways are there to write $2016$ as the difference of two squares?

So the question is asking for the integer solutions for $2016 = x^2-y^2$. The prime factorization of $2016$ is $2016=2^5\cdot3^2\cdot 7^1$. I’m not sure how should I continue from here, what would be the proper way?

Comment: Hint:  you can solve $x-y=a, x+y=b$ in integers if and only if $a,b$ have the same parity.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this a bit? By parity you mean that either $a$ and $b$ should both either be even or odd?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean by parity.  To get one example, write $2016=2\times 1008$.  We try to solve $x-y=2, x+y=1008$ and we get $x=505, y=503$.  Easy to verify that $505^2-503^2=2016$.

Comment: You can write $x-y=d, x+y=2016/d$ for divisor $d \mid 2016$, from which you get $x=\frac{1}{2}(d+\frac{2016}{d}), y=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{2016}{d}-d)$, and so by $d=2k$ eventually $x=k+\frac{504}{k},y=\frac{504}{k}-k$ for any divisor $k\mid 504$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rewriting $x^2 - y^2$ as $(x - y)(x + y)$, the problem is to count the integer solutions $(x,y)$ to all systems $x - y = a, x + y = b$, where $a, b$ are integers satisfying $ab = 2016$.

This is a nonsingular $2 \times 2$ linear system, so a unique choice of $x, y$ is always determined by $a, b$. The solutions $x = (a + b)/2, y = (b - a)/2$ are integers if and only if $a, b$ have the same parity.

Since $2016$ is even, $a, b$ must both be even, say $a = 2a', b = 2b'$. Then the problem is equivalent to counting the number of ways to write $a'b' = 504$.

Since $504 = 2^3 3^2 7$, the number $504$ has $4 \times 3 \times 2 = 24$ positive divisors $a'$. Taking into account negative divisors, we see that there are $48$ possible choices of $a'$, hence $48$ possibilities for the pair $(x,y)$.

Comment: +1. I would replace the abstract second paragraph by an explicit solution of this pair of equations. Then the parity assertion is obvious.

Comment: @EthanBolker Thanks, I've edited.

Comment: if you assume tha x and y are positive then there are 24 solutions (x,y). From each solution you can get 4 solutions (x,y),(-x,y),(x-y),(-x,-y) with arbitrary signs. so all in al there are 4*24=96 solutions

Comment: @miracle173 In his answer he found that there are 48 the possible values of a', not x and y. There is only 12 unique positive integer solutions for x and y according to wolfram alpha. I think this is since if you switch a' and b', x stays the same while y becomes negative so you are counting these extra duplicate solutions in the 24 solutions.  So when you multiply this 12 by 4 you do get 48.

Comment: @miracle173 For $x=24$, one gets $$(x,y)=(24+21,21-24),(x,y)=(21+24,24-21),(x,y)=(-21-24,-24+21),(x,y)=(-24-21,-21+24)$$There are $4$ for every $x$. But there's a catch! Not to choose $x=21$. Or, not to choose half of all divisors for every $x$. Thinking rather directly, $x=a^\prime+\frac{504}{a^\prime},y=\frac{504}{a^\prime}-a^\prime$. So for all positive and negative values of $a^\prime$, one gets $2\times24$ ways.

Comment: There are $48$ solutions when there are no restrictions on the signs of $x$ and $y$. Changing the sign of $x$ or $y$ always leads to a new solution (since there are no solutions with $x = 0$ or $y = 0$). So if $x, y$ are required to be positive, then there are $48/4 = 12$ solutions.

Comment: yes, you are all right. I misread the last sentence. There are 48 solutions.

Comment: "Since $2016$ is even, $a$, $b$ must both be even" is this because from the product $ab=2016$ we get that at least $a$ or $b$ must be even, but then since at least one of them is even say $a$ we can refer back to the parity condition and that would force $b$ to be even as well? @Anonymous

Comment: @Daniel Yes, that's right.

Comment: Great thanks! Also is there a way I could be wrong about the assumption that I made that we're looking for integer solutions since the problem statement didn't exactly tell that immediately? @Anonymous

Comment: Yes, it could be that it's asking about how many ways you can choose $x^2$ and $y^2$ rather than $x$ and $y$. In that case the answer would be $12$. Equivalently, it could be assuming $x, y \geq 0$, and then the answer would also be $12$.

Comment: I see! So it's probably a mistake in the problem statement not stating that the solutions should be integers? @Anonymous

Comment: To be honest, my initial interpretation was that, for instance, $16 - 9 = 7$ would count as *one* way of writing $7$ as a difference of squares, not four. You can either approach the problem the way I did and then divide by $4$ at the end, or you can require $x, y \geq 0$ and then you need $0 \leq a \leq b$.

Comment: The official solution seemed to be $12$. How did you came up to divide $\frac{48}{4}$ in order to get only the positive solutions?

Comment: Each solution such as $16 - 9 = 7$ corresponds to four of this kind: $4^2 - 3^2 = 7, 4^2 - (-3)^2 = 7, (-4)^2 - 3^2 = 7, (-4)^2 - (-3)^2 = 7$. If there were any solutions with $x = 0$ or $y = 0$, you'd need to be more careful than this, but for $2016$, there are none (since $2016$ isn't a perfect square).